# Roblox cloned part doesn't spawn in a random position

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to for each item in the table clone it from replicated storage to the workspace and put it at a random x and z coordinate (from the selected limit) for some reason it doesn't want to be random it spawns at it's position before it got put to replicated storage and when I try to put another a "for 1, math.random(5, 15),1 do" statment it completly breaks and gives me this error: "attempt to index nil with clone" at line 11 (2nd script in this post)

1st script

```
-- local variables --
local oF = game.ReplicatedStorage.Obstacles

local obstacleList = {oF.Pillar, oF.test}

local obstacleID = 1

-- spawn mechanics --
for i = 1, #obstacleList, 1 do
    local obstacleClone = obstacleList[obstacleID]:Clone()
    obstacleClone.Parent = game.Workspace
    obstacleList[obstacleID].Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-173, 173), -1.68, math.random(-173, 173))
    obstacleID += 1
end
```

2nd script

```
-- local variables --
local oF = game.ReplicatedStorage.Obstacles

local obstacleList = {oF.Pillar, oF.test}

local obstacleID = 1

-- spawn mechanics --
for i = 1, #obstacleList, 1 do
    for i = 1, math.random(5, 15), 1 do
        local obstacleClone = obstacleList[obstacleID]:Clone()
        obstacleClone.Parent = game.Workspace
        obstacleList[obstacleID].Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-173, 173), -1.68, math.random(-173, 173))
        obstacleID += 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you clone an object, any changes to the original are not replicated to the clones.

In your for-loop, you create a clone and put it into the world, but then you reposition the original object in ReplicatedStorage, not the clone. So, to fix your code, update the position of the newly created object instead.

```
local oF = game.ReplicatedStorage.Obstacles

-- create a list of obstacles
local obstacleList = {oF.Pillar, oF.test}

-- loop over all of the obstacles
for i, obstacle in ipairs(obstacleList) do
    -- clone the object
    local obstacleClone = obstacle:Clone()

    -- position the object
    obstacleClone.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-173, 173), -1.68, math.random(-173, 173))

    -- place the object into the world
    obstacleClone.Parent = game.Workspace
end
```